# Why don't we have a meta feeds bot in the chatroom now?

Tags: discussion, chat

As the first-day meta enthusiasm has cooled down a bit now, why don't we make a meta feeds bot for [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room), to post the latest meta questions like on all other SE sites? We can even name it Bookworm.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to use the 'manage feeds' option that room owners have to post questions from the RSS feed? I don't think you can customise the name of the 'bot' though; it's just auto-assigned.

Comment: @Aurora0001 you can customize the name of the feed - on [vi.se], we call it [`:r meta`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-388/r-meta)

Comment: @muru Ah, right, do you know how? I'm guessing that it's just a mod renaming the bot, although I couldn't find any info on Meta.SE about it.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I think any mod on chat (so any mod anywhere) can rename a feed bot - when I visit the user profile of a feed bot, for example the AU Meta bot, there's a form at the bottom of the card: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9zTU.png,

Comment: @muru: Just tested, and it looks like it is mod only (presumably to prevent abuse). I'm a room owner on Chat of Things (the IoT room) and can't change the feed name, so I presume that's the case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aurora0001 no problem. We have plenty of mods from other sites here, so ping any one of us if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**YES**

Like you state this a pretty common function across the SE network. It is useful and helpful for the same reason a ticker for regular site questions are. We want users to participate on both levels of the site and chat is a good place to do that.

Answer (score 1):

## We do.

There is a feed... I don't know what you're talking about ;)

But yes, let's have it post messages and be named **Bookworm**.

Comment: Already done that too :P